# Piping a series of node JS buffers to ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, redis, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm generating a series of frames and save them as buffers in a Redis database. Currently, I'm struggling to find out how I pipe them into FFmpeg in order to create a video. The goal of using this approach in favor of saving the frames on disk is to increase the performance. The length of a generated video won't exceed 3 minutes.

In the following function, I'm trying to collect all the frames from Redis, concatenate them together and save them into a temporary buffer using [stream-buffers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-buffers). Then I'm trying to use [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) to finally output the video.

```
let renderVideo = async () => {
  let data

  let frames = []

  for (let i = 0; i <= readyFrames.length - 1; i++) {
    data = await cache.get(`frame_${i}`)
    frames.push(data)
  }

  let allFramesTogether = Buffer.concat(frames) // Does
  tempReadableBuffer.put(allFramesTogether)     // not
  ffmpeg().input(tempReadableBuffer)            // work

  ffmpeg()
    .outputOptions(['-f image2pipe', '-pix_fmt yuv420p'])
    .videoCodec('libx264')
    .size(`${dimensions.width}x${dimensions.height}`)
    .format('mp4')
    .fps(FPS)
    .on('progress', function(progress) {
      console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done')
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('Processing finished !')
    })
    .on('stderr', function(stderrLine) {
      console.log('Stderr output: ' + stderrLine)
    })
    .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('Cannot process video: ' + err.message)
    })
    .save('test.mp4')
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any errors you're getting in the "does not work" part?

Comment: my app simply gets stuck and won't output any errors. i can log before the block, but not after the first line of the block

Comment: What's the returned data type of `cache.get(...)`? Does your frames array gets filled?

Comment: I'm getting string, which might be the problem.

Comment: After converting the data to buffer `data = Buffer.from(data)` the code runs through and exits with an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isStream' of undefined at runFfprobe`

Comment: I think you are creating two `ffmpeg()` instances, which are not linked. Maybe try: `ffmpeg().input(tempReadableBuffer).outputOptions(['-f image2pipe', '-pix_fmt yuv420p'])....etc.`?

Comment: @muradm you are right, after putting them together i get a little bit further. I'm getting a different ffmpeg related error: `ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: @JulianWeimer, great. Then what are the frames? What is their format? How do you acquire and write them? Normally, `ffmpeg` parses typed input, like `mp4` stream etc. So you can't just push arbitrary set of bytes. `ffmpeg` has to be able to distinguish the input type. If you have a bunch of `jpeg/png` images, then you should be able to concatenate them, search for `ffmpeg concatenate jpeg images` and then map it to usage of `fluent-ffmpeg`. In other words, you have to fit your data to input types supported by `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments and some research i was able to put something together:

Redis needs to be configured, so it outputs buffers, not strings

```
return_buffers: true
```

To concat the images saved as individual buffers i do

```
let allFramesTogether = Buffer.concat(frames)
```

ffmpeg can be run as a childprocess using spawn, while `-f` must be set to `image2pipe` and `-i` to `-`, so the images can be piped

```
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-r',
  `${FPS}`,
  '-f',
  'image2pipe',
  '-s',
  `${dimensions.width}x${dimensions.height}`,
  '-i',
  '-',
  '-vcodec',
  'libx264',
  '-crf',
  '25',
  '-pix_fmt',
  'yuv420p',
  'test.mp4'
])
```

To finally pipe the images i do `ffmpeg.stdin.write(allFramesTogether)` immediately after the code above, followed by `ffmpeg.stdin.end()`